# how to fix firebase error UISearchdisplayController is no longer supported. Migrate to UISearchController.?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.ios

- Xcode 11.3 version
- Xamarin.iOS version: 13.10.0.17 (Visual Studio Community)
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Auth version: 5.0.4.1
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudFirestore version: 0.13.3
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core version: 5.1.8

I have noticed this crash recently, only with app store distributed version [Test flight build]

The two crazy things are for me :

1. I’m not using “UISearchDisplayController” but the required new
   “UISearchController”.
2. Why is not crashing in local, but only on the AppStore version ?

Same application works fine in simulator without any issue. Same way if I'm installing app directly from xcode or using Diawi link it works fine.

I searched my whole project, no trace of UISearchDisplayController.
Is there any other possibility UISearchDisplayController is called elsewhere ?

Does anyone have answers for that ?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching I have got the solution.

I have opened my Main.Storyboard in source code editor and then I have search "searchDisplayController". And I have found two instance of it.
After removing it immediately I have uploaded new build to test flight and viola, it's working!