# App crashes in TestFlight with iOS 14.x without relevant information in log crashes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, testflight, ios14, macos-big-sur

I hope can help me with this specific bug: Apps crashes when is download from TestFlight without more information in log crash. This is the context:

- I tested the app in two iPhones (iOS 12.x and 14.x) from Xcode (running debug environment) and both work fine
- I tested the app in two iPhones (iOS 12.x and 14.x) from Xcode (running release environment) and both work perfectly
- I tested the app in two iPhones (iOS 12.x and 14.x) from TestFlight (release environment obviously) and iOS 12.x work perfectly but iOS 14.x crash when change view, I suppose trying to make a push

I extracted the log file from this crash and the information is not clear, for example **Exception Type** shows **EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)** and **Exception Note** says **EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY** with **Application Specific Information: abort() called**, but **Last Exception Backtrace** show data like memory access references without clear information. I paste the log for more information:

```
{"app_cohort":"2|date=1605650400000&sf=143468&tid=8a7f840419a4b41cead4435a4db1cd2e9dfc71748ee7df0c3818d1ee65685581&ttype=i","app_name":"xxxx","app_version":"2.3.4","timestamp":"2020-11-17 16:07:34.00 -0600","slice_uuid":"e3728715-3348-3b10-8cfc-31921c76aaa4","adam_id":1229864395,"build_version":"4.2","platform":2,"bundleID":"xxxx","share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 14.2 (18B92)","incident_id":"2119B11E-A68C-42E4-B112-BC780CB3CABA","name":"xxxx","is_beta":1}

Incident Identifier: 2119B11E-A68C-42E4-B112-BC780CB3CABA
Beta Identifier:     D9373011-28F5-47C4-94DF-92FCD0F70C4B
Hardware Model:      iPhone12,1
Process:             XXXXXXXXX [2537]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/56B7B416-89BD-4FAD-95C1-28EC076FD4DA/XXXXXXX.app/XXXXXXXX
Identifier:          XXXXXXXXX
Version:             4.2 (2.3.4)
AppStoreTools:       12B45a
AppVariant:          1:iPhone12,1:14
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           XXXXXXXXXXXX [1196]


Date/Time:           2020-11-17 16:07:34.7236 -0600
Launch Time:         2020-11-17 16:06:29.1481 -0600
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.2 (18B92)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.02.04
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1acc60878 0x1c11b6c50 0x1acb594a4 0x1aee6e488 0x1b5e5d720 0x1b5e5d938 0x1b5de7690 0x1aeee4f08 0x1af219fac 0x1b5e5d720 0x1b5de7690 0x1af21e4e4 0x1b5e5d720 0x1b5e5d938 0x1b5de7690 0x1af219160 0x1af21bc38 0x1af793010 0x100bc753c 0x100bc7360 0x1aeee598c 0x1aeeea1e8 0x1aeeea5ac 0x100bc9d18 0x100be6014 0x1ac85324c 0x1ac854db0 0x1ac8627ac 0x1acbdc11c 0x1acbd6120 0x1acbd521c 0x1c3c54784 0x1af60e200 0x1af613a74 0x100bde974 0x1ac8956c0)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d9b5f414 0x1d9b37000 + 164884
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f6077b40 0x1f6075000 + 11072
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b5f84b74 0x1b5f0e000 + 486260
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001c12bccf8 0x1c12a9000 + 81144
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001c12ade4c 0x1c12a9000 + 20044
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c11b6f64 0x1c11b0000 + 28516
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001c12bc0e0 0x1c12a9000 + 78048
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001c12bc06c 0x1c12a9000 + 77932
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ac854dc4 0x1ac851000 + 15812
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ac8627ac 0x1ac851000 + 71596
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001acbdc11c 0x1acb3b000 + 659740
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001acbd6120 0x1acb3b000 + 635168
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001acbd521c 0x1acb3b000 + 631324
13  GraphicsServices                0x00000001c3c54784 0x1c3c51000 + 14212
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001af60e200 0x1aea47000 + 12349952
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001af613a74 0x1aea47000 + 12372596
16  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx                  0x0000000100bde974 0x100ab0000 + 1239412
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001ac8956c0 0x1ac894000 + 5824
```

I tested my app with Xcode 12.1 and then with Xcode 12.2 with BigSur but I think it doesn't matter, because the real problem is between TestFlight and iOS 14.x. Also, the app is developed in Objective-C yet without Swift. Anyone has another way to get the error or know what is happening?

Aditional:
I attach symbolic crash
[image]

Comment: "I extracted the log file from this crash":  How? Since it crashed on Testflight, Xcode/Organizer/Crashes, it doesn't appear there, with mire info, and a symbolicate trace?

Comment: @Larme into the iPhone go to Settings - Privacy - Analytics & Improvements - Analytics Data and there you will see all the logs

Comment: Would you mind symbolize the crashlog, or check in Xcode (https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=nra79npr )? Note that it might appear also in iTunesConnect.

Comment: @Larme done! I have more information to solve it! But I attach the image in my post

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/125520 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819165/installed-app-from-testflight-crashes-due-to-alleged-uisearchdisplaycontroller https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248010/how-to-fix-firebase-error-uisearchdisplaycontroller-is-no-longer-supported-migr etc.

Comment: @Larme thanks so much! I had read about this bug but I didn't know if it could be the real problem because I was not sure, but with this I am completely sure. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installed App from TestFlight crashes due to alleged UISearchDisplayController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819165/installed-app-from-testflight-crashes-due-to-alleged-uisearchdisplaycontroller)

Comment: @Larme I am testing yet... but I am sure it could solve my problem